# Share auto-defined function in project

Tags: c++11, header-files, auto

Please excuse this c++ newbie question. I want to share a function `rnd()` in a larger project. It is defined through:

```
#include<random>
#include<functional>

std::mt19937 generator (123);
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);
auto rnd = std::bind(dist,std::ref(generator));
```

I have tried putting the above definition in a header file, but get 'duplicate symbols' errors, and in a separate .cpp file which nets me 'undefined symbols' errors.

Comment: If you want to put this into a header, all three variables must be `inline`.

Comment: Note that since seeding a generator is expensive you would typically want to use _one_ generator (per thread).

Answer (score 0):

A bit of digging yielded the answer:

1) *Explicitly type* the result of `std::bind` using `std::function` in the auxilliary *.cpp file with the definition.

```
#include<random>
#include<functional>
std::mt19937 generator (123);
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);
std::function<double (void)> mt_rnd = std::bind(dist,std::ref(generator));
```

2) Explicitly declare the function in any other project file, again using `std::function`

```
extern std::function<double ()> mt_rnd;
```